# Image with rotatex is blank on safari and iphone until clicked

Tags: html, css, image, safari, responsive-design

i have a filpbook that works well for me. I'm using chrome on pc. Here is the codes:

https://jsfiddle.net/b7meLj1x/

CSS:

```
.zone11{
   height: 700px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.book11{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flipbook-open .cover11{
    transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flipbook-open .page11{
    transform: rotateX(10deg) rotateY(-180deg);
    z-index: 2;
}
.cover11{
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all 3.5s;
}
.back-cover11{
    z-index: -3;
}
.cover11, .back-cover11{
   height: 400px;
    width: 320px;
    background: #3f0035;
     border-radius: 2px 20px 20px 2px;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px gray;
    transform: rotateX(10deg);
    transform-origin: center left;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.page11{
   height: 380px;
    width: 310px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px 10px 10px 2px;
    transform: rotateX(10deg);
    transform-origin: center left;
    z-index: -1;
}
.last-page11{
   height: 380px;
    width: 310px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px 10px 10px 2px;
    transform: rotateX(10deg);
    transform-origin: center left;
    z-index: -2;
}
.page11:nth-child(2){
    transition-duration: 3s;
}
.page11:nth-child(3){
    transition-duration: 2.6s;
}
.page11:nth-child(4){
    transition-duration: 2.2s;
}
.page11:nth-child(5){
    transition-duration: 1.8s;
}
.page11:nth-child(6){
    transition-duration: 1.4s;
}
.flipbook-open .page11:nth-child(2){
    transition-duration: 6s;
}
.flipbook-open .page11:nth-child(3){
    transition-duration: 5.6s;
}
.flipbook-open .page11:nth-child(4){
    transition-duration: 5.2s;
}
.flipbook-open .page11:nth-child(5){
    transition-duration: 4.8s;
}
.flipbook-open .page11:nth-child(6){
    transition-duration: 4.4s;
}
.last-page11 img{
    height: 360px;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -2;
}
.cover11 img{
    height: 380px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    z-index: -1;
    
}
```

HTML and JAVACRIPT:

```
<div class="zone11">
    <div class="book11">    
        <div class="cover11"><img alt="" src="cover.jpg"></div>
        <div class="page11"></div>
        <div class="page11"></div>
        <div class="page11"></div>
        <div class="page11"></div>
        <div class="page11"></div>
        <div class="last-page11"><img src="page.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back-cover11"></div>
    </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector('.book11').addEventListener('click', function() {
document.querySelector('.zone11').classList.toggle('flipbook-open');
});
</script>
```

If i open it with safari or with iphone (even with chrome) the cover image of the flipbook is white. When i click it to open the flipbook becomes visible. When i close the book it turn white again.

I notice that the problem is for the rotatex. Removing all the rotatex i can see all the images but i lose the animation that i wanted.

Thanks if someone wants to help me.

Comment: What version of Safari or IOS are you on?

Comment: I tried with different versions. On iphone i see this problem even with google chrome.

Comment: Chrome is basically the same as Safari on IOS. Specifically which versions of IOS are you trying?

Comment: 14.1.2 for example. I also tried on non-mine devices so I don't know the version

Comment: Look at caniuse.com to see what of the CSS you are using is not supported. For example, backface-visibility isn't supported on IOS14.2.1 - you need the prefix -webkit-. If you make your code into a runnable snippet (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I could try it on a later version.

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth, i hope this is ok: https://jsfiddle.net/b7meLj1x/
I took the images random on the internet.
It works ok for me, but if i use safari doesn't word well.

p.s. I tried with -webkit-backface-visibility but it does not change anything to me.
Removing the rotatex the problem is solved